# Fresh install of Windows 8.1 Pro on new SSD stuck on ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ssd

I bought a new SSD and fresh installed Windows 8.1 Pro on it. Everything is fine except that it is stuck in ethernet mode. I can't figure out how to turn on the WiFi. This has never happened to me before. I tried toggling the WiFi switch, but that didn't work. I tried to restart and that didn't work. I have my laptop HDD that I removed to install the SSD. I plugged the HDD back in and Ubuntu 15.04 loaded up normally and the WiFi was working so this rules out hardware issues. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on and possibly help me? If it helps, my laptop is a Lenovo G50-70.

Additional information: In the bios menu, Wireless is enabled and SATA controller mode is AHCI,

Comment: Does Windows recognize your WiFi adapter at all? Instead of the mass storage being the cause, a adapter driver issue would seem to be more logical...

Answer (score 0):

Find the model/hardware id of your wifi card and install/reinstall the necessary driver. You may even be able to reach a Lenovo support page that lists all the recommended drivers for your laptop. Maybe try there first.